# How to deal with players always betting big post flop

Tags: poker-strategy

I have been playing a lot of poker lately in a casino and am learning a lot.

However there is one aspect of the game that gets me every time. So much so that I will usually leave the table and go find another if i see it too much.

Here is the scenario:

1/2 no limit

Say I am position 1 have AK I raise $10

3 players call to see flop

flop comes out Q, 10, 5 off suit

Player 1 (ME) Bet $20

Player 2 Call

Player 3 Raise $100

Player 4 Fold

Would it be good to fold here or play it out?

Say the turn is 6

What to do then?

The river can be anything for right now i am just wondering how to play this part, I am thinking depending on the river it will be a completely different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You opened to 5 blinds.

You then get called by 3 people and the flop is very bad for you and you’re under the gun. I’d chose to check-call or check-fold depending on the action. No reason to Cbet in this flop against 3 villain.

You don’t say anything about your read on the villain. We know is aggressive and it looks like LAG, so the best strategy is to tighten your game and wait to hit. You can be certain he’ll give you action when you hit.

I would say, given the dynamic of the table, open to 2.5 o 3bb rather than five. It’s not managing its main purpose which is to isolate.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is what defines the difference between limit and no limit poker. In a limit game this hand is good enough most of the time to make an auto call on the flop when your raised, in no limit this hand with this kind of action is a problem. It is not a hand you want to automatically fold nor a hand you want to automatically call with.

On the flop, you have a hand that has a good range to improve, you have a hand that maybe is the best hand.

The problem here is figuring out why your opponent is doing what he is doing. Does he have a pair, a set, a draw? Or does he think the flop did not hit you and is trying to take you off the hand? You weigh your outs, you consider how credible your opponents bet is, and how accurate you are at accessing what is around you, and then decide to fold, call or raise which are all valid things to do at this point in the hand. How well that works, your actual EV on the hand just depends on how well you can size up the situation and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to play sometimes against aggressive players. A good rule of thumb when facing a big bet/raise is to look at your range and fold a part of it, depending on the actual size. The bigger the bet/raise the more you should fold.

In your case AK is a pretty bad hand for your range. You can have all sets, two pair, top pair, strong straight draws and backdoor flushdraws. There is even a player behind you that can backraise you. You should definitely fold.

Answer (score 0):

You opened for 5x and got 3 callers. That is a loose table. Why open for so much? You know you can get action on the flop.  A 3x open is more standard.

On the flop you have 10 outs. TT or QQ sh/would have re-raised pre. 55 could just call. Bet $20 (1/2 pot) to see where you are is OK but you are not likely to fold out 3 callers.  You can just check to an aggressive table. That table likely hit someone. You have to call $80 with $180 in the pot so you are getting 2.25:1. 10 outs (3.7:1) is not good enough is call. A J could win you a big hand so it is maybe a call. I fold here.

I don't like the way you played the hand on that table. It just cost you $30 to fold a flop. You are putting too much money in the pot.  You could have opened for $6 checked the flop and played that hand for $6. You are on a table where you can get action. You want to see flops cheap with quality hands. You can play 89s cheap on a table like this as when you hit can get paid off. A loose aggressive table can be very profitable.  Play tight and let them bet for you.

5x pre then 1/2 the pot is not balanced. I would rather see 3x pre and then bet 2/3 pot on the flop or check. You can rep QQ and they can't. If you bet $6 pre you could have checked and maybe be facing a $40 bet. Here you can come back for $100 and put the pressure on them. They would raise pre with QQ and just call this flop with QQ to keep you in the hand. You are (well should) only getting called by QT, TT, or 55. I would still fold here but my point is this is still $100 and you have fold equity.